# Perl: Regex with Variables inside?

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a more elegant way of bringing a variable into a pattern than this (put the patterin in a string before instead of using it directly in //)??

```
my $z = "1";  # variable
my $x = "foo1bar";

my $pat = "^foo".$z."bar\$";   
if ($x =~ /$pat/)
{
  print "\nok\n";
}
```

Comment: `/^foo${z}bar$/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need to delimit the variable's name so to be recognized inside a string, `/^foo${z}bar$/`<sup>†</sup>

Use the [`qr` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) to build a variable with a regex pattern

```
my $pat = qr/^foo${z}bar$/;
```

If the delimiters are `'` the variables aren't interpolated, just like for normal strings.

This operator is the best way to build patterns ahead of time as it builds a proper regex pattern, accepting everything that one can use in a pattern in a regex.  It also takes modifiers, so for one the above can be written as

```
my $pat = qr/^foo $z bar$/x;
```

for a little extra clarity (but careful with omitting those `{}`).<sup>†</sup>

The initial description from the above `perlop` link (examples and discussion follow):

> `qr/STRING/msixpodualn`
>
> This operator quotes (and possibly compiles) its STRING as a regular expression. STRING is interpolated the same way as PATTERN in `m/PATTERN/`. If "'" is used as the delimiter, no variable interpolation is done. Returns a Perl value which may be used instead of the corresponding `/STRING/msixpodualn` expression. The returned value is a normalized version of the original pattern. It magically differs from a string containing the same characters: `ref(qr/x/)` returns "Regexp"; however, dereferencing it is not well defined (you currently get the normalized version of the original pattern, but this may change).

The same goes for normal strings, `"^foo${z}\$"`, and most patterns work.  But we often need to do more work since many regex patterns in a double-quoted string have their own meaning.

An example are escaped sequences, which are treated as string "escapes" and interpolated as such, or attempted (`\s`, `\w`... fail with warnings for not being recognized as valid escapes).  As they need be passed to the regex untouched anyway most escapes need be escaped (`\\w`), depriving `\` of its special meaning -- but some (`\x27`) need to stay as they are!

Single-quoting the string solves this (no need to escape things) but then variable interpolation is off.  The `qr` has none of these complications as it's meant for a regex pattern.

---

<sup>†</sup> Once a variable is getting interpolated it may be a good idea to escape special characters that may be hiding in it, that could throw off the regex, using [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta)-based `\Q ... \E`

```
my $pat = qr/^foo \Q$z\E bar$/x;
```

If this is used then the variable name need not be delimited either

```
my $pat = qr/^foo\Q$z\Ebar$/;
```

Thanks to [Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173773/h%c3%a5kon-h%c3%a6gland) for bringing this up.

Comment: Maybe also consider escaping special characters in `$z`: `\Q$z\E`